# How and where to implement functions that check for "partial equality"

Tags: c++

Let's say we have the following class:

```
// Foo.h
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo();
    int getA() const;
    int getB() const;
    bool getC() const;
    bool getD() const;
    bool operator==(const Foo& other) const;

  private:
    int a;
    int b;
    bool c;
    bool d;
}

// Foo.cpp
bool Foo::operator==(const Foo& other) const
{
    return (a == other.a && b == other.b && c == other.c && d == other.d);
}
```

Due to changing requirements we now need to implement an additional function that compares `Foo`s - but does not care if the `d` value in the Foo are equal or not. The question is now where to implement this function.

It could be implemented near / in the class that needs it...

```
// Bar.cpp
bool compareFoosExceptForD(const Foo& lhs, const& Foo rhs)
{
    return (lhs.getA() == rhs.getA() && lhs.getB() == rhs.getB() && lhs.getC() == rhs.getC())
}
```

but that reeks of both feature envy and code duplication (e.g. if Foo gets a `int e` we need to update both its `==` operator and the `compareFoosExceptForD` function).

Putting it inside `Foo` would resolve both points above, but also does not feel entirely right as *"equal, but don't care about D"* is a very special snowflake function that is unlikely to be used anywhere except by the `Bar` class that caused its inclusion.

```
// Foo.h
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo();
    //...
    bool equalIgnoringD(const& Foo other);
    //...
}

// Foo.cpp
bool Foo::equalIgnoringD(const Foo& other) const
{
    return (a == other.a && b == other.b && c == other.c);
}

bool Foo::operator==(const Foo& other) const
{
    return (equalIgnoringD(other) && d == other.d);
}
```

Is there a better way to resolve this that I am missing right now, or is my gut just acting up and adding the function to Foo is the right way to go?

(**Note**: The example above is rather simplified. `Foo` has more functions & members, and the `int`s and `bool`s are (in reality) classes and structs on their own, which do implement the `==` operator.)

Comment: If you're looking for design hints, I'd suggest not abstracting away all the types and names. In a situation like this, knowing what you're working with is kind of important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this whole question is some sort of opinion based. I personally would take the second path and implement `equalIgnoringD(const Foo& other)` as member of `Foo` and reuse that function in the `operator==` instead of implementing the `compareFoosExceptForD` in `Bar.cpp`.

In case you really add another member `e` to `Foo` later on, you don't have to remember updating `Bar` separatley. Imagine you add `e` to `Foo` a year from now. I know for sure that I'd forget updating `Bar`, because clearly there is no further link between `Foo` and `Bar` that indicates the dependency. That's why I'd personally accept having a "very special snowflake function" in `Foo`. Besides, who knows if this function is that special anyway. You might end up having to use it in another place later on.

As for your question if there is a better way to resolve this: I couldn't think of one spontaneously. And as ShadowRanger commented, the "best" solution always depends on the whole context.